# Gradle pendant to Ant's unjar and execute

Tags: gradle

I want to convert a simple ANT build file to Gradle. The task looks like

```
<property name="app"           value="myapp"/>
<property name="build"         value=".build"/>
<property name="build.classes" value="${build}/classes"/>
<property name="build.jars"    value="${build}/jars"/>

...

<target name="native">
    <unjar src="${build.jars}/mylib.jar" dest="${build}" overwrite="true">
        <patternset>
            <include name="foobar-*.dll"/>
        </patternset>
    </unjar>
    <exec executable="script.cmd" dir="${build.jars}">
        <arg value="--verbose"/>
        <arg value="-H:Name=${app}"/>
    </exec>
    ...
</target>
```

I'd start with following code below the `application { ... }`:

```
tasks.register('native') {
   doLast {
      ...
      commandLine script.cmd, '--verbose', "-H:Name=${app}"
   }
}
```

but what to write in the `doLast` block? Are there pendants for `unjar` and other ANT commands available or do I have to write them from scratch with Groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, it can be translated quite easily like this:

```
String app = 'myapp'
String build = '.build'
String buildClasses = "${build}/classes"
String buildJars ="${build}/jars"

...

tasks.register('native') {
  doLast {
    ant.unjar(src: "${build.jars}/mylib.jar", dest: build, overwrite: true) {
      patternset() {
        include(name: 'foobar-*.dll'
      }
    }
    ant.exec(executable: 'script.cmd', dir: buildJars) {
      arg(value: '--verbose')
      arg(value: "-H:Name=${app}")
    }
    ...
  }
}
```